# Rotation of 3 digits iteratively clockwise

Tags: c++, windows, for-loop, rotation

Design a C++ Code that asks the user to enter three integers. The program will iteratively rotate these numbers clockwise. Take input from the user for number of rotation.

```
int a,b,c,n1,n2,n3,n;
cout<<"Enter number of rotations :"<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter 3 integers: "<<endl;
cin>>n1;
cin>>n2;
cin>>n3;
 for(int i=1 ;i<=n; i=i+3)//1,4,7,10...
{
    a=n1;
    b=n2;
    c=n3;
    cout<<"After"<<i<<" "<<"clock cycle"<<c<<a<<b<<endl;    
}   
for(int i=2 ; i<=n ; i=i+3)//2,5,8,11...
{
    a=n1;
    b=n2;
    c=n3;
    cout<<"After"<<i<<" "<<"clock cycle"<<b<<c<<a<<endl;    
}  
for(int i=3; i<=n ; i=i+3)//3,6,9,12,15...
{
    a=n1;
    b=n2;
    c=n3;
    cout<<"After"<<i<<" "<<"clock cycle"<<a<<b<<c<<endl;
}
```

this is my code the only problem i am facing is that number of rotations are not symetric.

Comment: If you put no effort in asking, no one will make an effort to answer. Please see the how to ask page in the help centre

Comment: I suggest you take the three numbers as elements of a vector and rotate the vector with std::rotate

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 ok i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take the three numbers as elements of a `vector` and rotate the `vector` with `std::rotate`:

Something on the following lines:

```
std::vector<int> vec(3);
for(auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cin >> elem;
}
```

---

To [rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1, vec.end());
```